# Multiplying value corresponding to a label in one dataframe by all values with the same label in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the two following dataframes:

```
df.head()
Out[256]: 
           NUTS_ID        t2m        HDD    DK_HDD
Date                                              
2018-01-01     AT1   3.501755  14.498245  0.005033
2018-01-02     AT1   7.686142  10.313858  0.003580
2018-01-03     AT1  10.249952   7.750048  0.002690
2018-01-04     AT1  14.330340   3.669660  0.001274
2018-01-05     AT1   2.928884  15.071116  0.005232

df2.head()
Out[257]: 
                2016         2017            2018  
NUTS_ID                                               
AT1      5104.023345  4422.809561     4363.874907  
AT2      3904.562866  3383.436322     3338.351485  
AT3      6954.504900  6026.314672     5946.013052  
BE1         0.000000     0.000000     2724.610387  
BE2         0.000000     0.000000    14187.414251
```

I want to multiply the value in `df2` corresponding to each index in one column by all the values in a column of `df` with the same code. As an example: In `df2`, I want to take the value corresponding to index `AT1` and column `2018` (4363.874907) and multiply it by all the values in the column `DK_HDD` with `NUTS_ID = AT1`, then the same for `AT2`, and so on.

The result I expect would be a new dataframe with the structure:

```
           NUTS_ID    Product
Date                                              
2018-01-01     AT1    21.9633
2018-01-02     AT1    15.6226
2018-01-03     AT1    11.7388
2018-01-04     AT1     5.5595
2018-01-05     AT1    22.8317
```

I tried using `mul` but I got NaN and also lost the `NUTS_ID` column. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Just in case it's necessary:

```
df.dtypes
Out[262]: 
NUTS_ID     object
t2m        float64
HDD        float64
DK_HDD     float64
dtype: object

df2.dtypes
Out[263]: 
2016    float64
2017    float64
2018    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge()` data frames then do the calculation.  Need index columns in `merge()` output hence use of `reset_index()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date           NUTS_ID        t2m        HDD    DK_HDD
                                              
2018-01-01     AT1   3.501755  14.498245  0.005033
2018-01-02     AT1   7.686142  10.313858  0.003580
2018-01-03     AT1  10.249952   7.750048  0.002690
2018-01-04     AT1  14.330340   3.669660  0.001274
2018-01-05     AT1   2.928884  15.071116  0.005232"""), sep="\s+")
df = df.set_index("Date")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""NUTS_ID                2016         2017            2018  
                                               
AT1      5104.023345  4422.809561     4363.874907  
AT2      3904.562866  3383.436322     3338.351485  
AT3      6954.504900  6026.314672     5946.013052  
BE1         0.000000     0.000000     2724.610387  
BE2         0.000000     0.000000    14187.414251  """), sep="\s+")
df2 = df2.set_index("NUTS_ID")

(df2
 # need NUTS_ID to be a column to allow merge
 .reset_index()
 .merge(df.reset_index(), on="NUTS_ID", how="outer")
 .assign(Product=lambda dfa: dfa["2018"]*dfa["DK_HDD"])
 .drop(columns=["2016","2017","2018","HDD","DK_HDD","t2m"])
 .dropna()
 .set_index("Date")
 
)
```

### output

```
    NUTS_ID Product
Date        
2018-01-01  AT1 21.963382
2018-01-02  AT1 15.622672
2018-01-03  AT1 11.738823
2018-01-04  AT1 5.559577
2018-01-05  AT1 22.831794
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
>>> df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
>>> df3 = (df1.loc[:, ['NUTS_ID']]
        .assign(
            Product=df1.apply(
                lambda x: df2.loc[x['NUTS_ID'], 
                str(x.name.year)] * x['DK_HDD'], 
            axis=1)
            )
    )

           NUTS_ID    Product
Date                         
2018-01-01     AT1  21.963382
2018-01-02     AT1  15.622672
2018-01-03     AT1  11.738823
2018-01-04     AT1   5.559577
2018-01-05     AT1  22.831794
```

Note: If `df2` column names are of type `int`, use `x.name.year` instead of `str(x.name.year)`.

Comment: Sayandip Dutta, thanks for your help. `df2` columns are `float64`. Unfortunately I'm getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'`.

Comment: Ah, I thought your `df1.index` was datetime index. Let me fix it.

Comment: @JavierSando Fixed, could you check if it works now?

Comment: unfortunately no... same error, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'`. `df1` has a `datetime` index and `NUTS_ID` and `DK_HDD` columns. `df2` has `NUTS_ID` index and `2016` to `2018` columns.